# RegEx match all characters between two separate strings

Tags: regex

I would like to capture only the text of the description (all text and line breaks between `Description:` and `Send file:`).

The text is below:

---

Summary: Mr. Darcy drew his chair a little towards her, and said, “You
cannot have a righ

Description: A short dialogue on the subject of the country ensued, on either
side calm and concise--and soon put an end to by the entrance of Charlotte
and her sister, just returned from her walk. The tete-a-tete surprised them.
Mr. Darcy related the mistake which had occasioned his intruding on Miss
Bennet, and after sitting a few minutes longer without saying much to
anybody, went away.

Send file: No
Needed: Within 10 business days

---

I tried this:

```
Description:\s(.*\n?(?=\nSend file:))
```

and this:

```
Description:\s(.*\n(?=Send file:))
```

Comment: What OS/Editor/Program/RDBMS are you using?  Not all flavors of regex are created equal.

Comment: Your first regex looks like [it works](https://regex101.com/r/K4Q2W8/1).

Answer (score 1):

Without more info, this seems to work.  Make sure multiline is enabled:

```
^Description: (.*)\s*^Send file:
```

[See example here.](https://regex101.com/r/nowivO/1)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different format. The parens make it more clear to read.

```
^(Description: )(.*)\s*(^Send file:)
```